# Question about an integral trick

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

This is an excerpt from brilliant.org on integral tricks:

> A similar method to the above is to reverse the interval of
>   integration: to "integrate backwards." For a function $f$ and real
>   numbers $a < b$,
>
> $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx.$
>
> Instead of the function being centered at $0$, the function is now
>   centered at $(\tfrac{a+b}{2})$. Then,
>
> $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b f(x) + f(a+b-x) \, dx.$

I understand that the trick is to integrate backwards, from $b$ towards $a$, but I don't understand what is meant by that the function is centered at $(\tfrac{a+b}{2})$. What is meant by that and why is it significant? Also, how is the last integral derived?

Comment: The phrase "Instead of the function being centered at 0, the function is now centered at (a+b2)" is meaningless and should be ignored. If you want to interpret the change of variable $x=a+b-y$ geometrically, note that it coincides with the equation of the reflection having $\frac{a+b}{2}$ as its center.

Comment: This is how I imagine it in simple terms: I have $a<b$, normally the integration happens from $a$ towards $b$ but with this expression, it is from $b$ towards $a$. And $(a+b)/2$ is just the center of that interval and $dx$ is actually reflected with respect to that point. But I don't understand how the function can be 'centered' and what is meant by that. Do you refer to my formulation too?

Comment: As I said, the "centered at" statement is meaningless.

Comment: It means that the new integrand (namely $f(x) + f(a+b - x)$)  has the property that $f(c + u) = f(c-u)$, where $c$ is the center ($(a+b)/2$) and $u$ is any number from $0$ to $(b-a)/2$. Such a symmetrized function may possibly be easier to integrate. For instance, if $a = -1, b = +1$ and $f$ is an odd function, then the new integrand will be zero everywhere, hence the integral will evidently be zero. I agree it's badly written (esp. in referring to an as-yet-undescribed integrand!), but I wouldn't go as far as "meaningless."

Comment: Is there a name for the property $f(c+u)=f(c-u)$? I searched for 'symmetrical function' but I couldn't find anything. Edit: This is actually an even function with a center in $c$ right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we let $x=a+b-y$ then when $x=a$, $y=a+b-a=b$ and when $x=b$, $y=a+b-b=a$ and $dx=-dy$, so
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_b^af(a+b-y)(-dy)=\int_a^bf(a+b-y)dy=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$
Where running the integral backwards changes its sign and we renamed the variable of integration back to $x$. Then
$$\begin{align}\int_a^bf(x)dx&=\frac12\int_a^bf(x)dx+\frac12\int_a^bf(x)dx\\
&=\frac12\int_a^bf(x)dx+\frac12\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx\\
&=\frac12\int_a^b\left(f(x)+f(a+b-x)\right)dx\end{align}$$
The function is centered at $\frac{b+a}2$ means it is even about that point: let $g(x)=\frac12\left(f(x)+f(a+b-x)\right)$. Then
$$\begin{align}g\left(\frac{b+a}2-x\right)&=\frac12\left(f\left(\frac{b+a}2-x\right)+f\left(b+a-\frac{b+a}2+x\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(f\left(b+a-\frac{b+a}2-x\right)+f\left(\frac{b+a}2+x\right)\right)\\
&=\frac12\left(f\left(b+a-\left(\frac{b+a}2+x\right)\right)+f\left(\frac{b+a}2+x\right)\right)\\
&=g\left(\frac{b+a}2+x\right)\end{align}$$
Usually when we talk about even functions the point of reflection is implicitly $0$ so $g(-x)=g(x)$.

Here's an integral from the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics and the Putnam exam:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\frac{d\theta}{1+\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta}&=\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta}+\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt2}\left(\frac{\pi}2-\theta\right)}\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta}+\frac{1}{1+\cot^{\sqrt2}\left(\theta\right)}\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta}+\frac{\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta}{\tan^{\sqrt2}\theta+1}\right)d\theta\\
&=\frac12\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}1d\theta=\frac{\pi}4\end{align}$$
Cool how folding about $\theta=\frac{\pi}4$ knocked down what seemed like a very daunting integral.

Comment: Great explanation and interesting application of the trick. Can you explain how you derived $dx=-dy$?

Comment: If $x$ is a function of $y$, $x=x(y)$ then $dx=x^{\prime}(y)dy$. In the current context $x=a+b-y$, so $x^{\prime}(y)=-1$.

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you for your great explanation again. Can you suggest more problems like this for practicing?

Comment: OK, here's one of my favorite integrals. Many ways to solve it, but this time via folding. $$f(e)=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{d\theta}{1+e\cos\theta}$$ With $0< e< 1$. If you apply the folding transformation, then $\cos^2\theta=\frac12(1+\cos2\theta)$ then $\phi=2\theta$ and a little more effort you can get to $$f(e_n)=\frac{\sqrt{1-e_{n+1}^2}}{\sqrt{1-e_n^2}}f(e_{n+1})$$ Then we have $$\sqrt{1-e^2}f(e)=\sqrt{1-e_0^2}f(e_0)=\sqrt{1-e_1^2}f(e_1)=\dots=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt{1-e_n^2}f(e_n)$$ And since $0< e_{n+1}< e_n^2$ we can evaluate the original integral. See if you can walk through the steps.

Answer (score 2):

From here

$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx\\\iff \int_a^b f(x) \, dx +\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(x) \, dx+\int_a^b f(a+b-x) \, dx\\\iff 2\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \int_a^b f(x)+f(a+b-x) \, dx\\\iff \int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_a^b f(x) + f(a+b-x) \, dx$$